# angular2 and query tablesorter - how to execute a typescript function after html table is loaded

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using angular2 with html tables and jquery tablesorter.

```
tableSorter(){
    $("[data-sort=table]").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[0,1]]
    });
}
```

How to I execute tableSorter after the table is ready?

I get this error which I susptect is due to the data not being ready.

```
tablesorter TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

After a page has been completed, Angular2 fires a **NavigationEnd**-event which can be catched . I have used this approach in the following example:

```
import { Component, Injector }      from '@angular/core';
import { Event, NavigationEnd, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
declare var $:any;  // To get a grip on jQuery...

@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: 'part/nav',
    styleUrls: ['cms/cms/nav.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class NavComponent {

    constructor(router:Router) {
        router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                // Close menu in case of small screen...
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide'); // same way with tablesorter...
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I bet you can use the same method with tablesorter as long as you can address them trough classnames...